# How to Display the sum of Columns on the footer part written in a CTE and Join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I am getting the total in an adjacent way,so I want How to Display the sum of Columns on the footer part written  in a CTE and Join query

```
        1  2  3
        1  1  1
    Tot 2  0  0
        0  3  0
        0  0  4
```

The query is:

```
;WITH t1
AS (
    SELECT DeptID
        ,COUNT(EmpID) AS NewJoinees
    FROM EmployeeDetails AS EmployeeDetails_7
    WHERE (DATEPART(yyyy, DOJ) = 2017)
        AND (DATEPART(mm, DOJ) = 02)
        AND datepart(mm, DOJ) >= 02
        AND STATUS = 0
    GROUP BY DeptID
    WITH ROLLUP
    )
    ,t3
AS (
    SELECT DeptID
        ,COUNT(EmpID) AS Resigned
    FROM EmployeeDetails AS EmployeeDetails_7
    WHERE (DATEPART(yyyy, deactivate) = 2017)
        AND (DATEPART(mm, deactivate) = 02)
        AND datepart(mm, deactivate) >= 02
        AND STATUS = 1
    GROUP BY DeptID
    WITH ROLLUP
    )
    ,t4
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DeptID
        ,Tobehired AS ToBeHired
        ,Openposition AS OpenPositions
        ,STATUS AS Status1
    FROM RecruitmentDetails1
    WHERE Tobehired = 45
    )
    ,t5
AS (
    SELECT DeptID
        ,Deptname
    FROM DepartmentDetails
    WHERE DeptID <> 'BPO'
        AND DeptID <> 'Finance'
        AND DeptID <> 'Accounts'
        AND DeptID <> 'Mgmt'
    )
SELECT t5.Deptname AS Department
    ,CASE 
        WHEN TotalHeadCount IS NULL
            THEN '0'
        ELSE TotalHeadCount
        END AS TotalHeadCount
    ,CASE 
        WHEN NewJoinees IS NULL
            THEN '0'
        ELSE NewJoinees
        END AS NewJoinees
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Resigned IS NULL
            THEN '0'
        ELSE Resigned
        END AS Resigned
    ,t4.Tobehired AS ToBeHired
    ,t4.OpenPositions AS OpenPositions
    ,t4.Status1 AS Status1
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID
FULL OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.DeptID = t3.DeptID
FULL OUTER JOIN t4 ON t1.DeptID = t4.DeptID
FULL OUTER JOIN t5 ON t1.DeptID = t5.DeptID
```

Comment: Seems like you missed some initial part of the query.

Comment: MySQL and ms sql server are two different products. Pls use only the relevant product tags

Comment: ';with t1 as (
SELECT DeptID, COUNT(EmpID) AS TotalHeadCount  FROM EmployeeDetails          
WHERE (datepart(yyyy,DOJ) between 2005 and 2017) and Status =0
group by DeptID WITH ROLLUP
),'